# Vlookup - how to deal with #n/a errors - office 365

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm using MS Excel O365 Business in version 1905 (compilation 11629.20196). In this case i have created two sheets: 1) "Orders"

[image]

2) Order_status

[image]

NUMBER_ORDER Column (in Order_status sheet) has been created all cells by drop down list giving source to column in "Orders" sheet: `=Orders!$B$2:$B$1048576`

Now i'd like to create a formula in DESC_ORDER from "Order_status" sheet which automatically writes data from cell in "NUMBER_ORDER" Column. By writing that formula i have "#N/A" Error (despite the correction all data in the 2 sheets).

**What I've tried?**

I tried in a few different ways:

1) I've written `=VLOOKUP(E2,Orders!$A:$B,COLUMN(Orders!$A$2:$A$1048576))` then i formated text to column the DESC_ORDER in "Orders" sheet. It didn't work.

2) Then i tried this VLOOKUP by changing to text in E2 cell: `=VLOOKUP(TEXT(E2,"#"),Orders!$A:$B,COLUMN(Orders!$A$2:$A$1048576))`. Didn't work too.

3) Then i modified to Trim in E2 cell: `=VLOOKUP(TRIM(E2),Orders!$A:$B,COLUMN(Orders!$A$2:$A$1048576))` Didn't help.

4) Later i created 2 views "Orders" for these 2 columns for in "Orders" sheet. And "Orders_status" in columns from "Order_status" sheet. The i rewrote that formula: `=VLOOKUP(Order_status,Orders!$A:$B,1,FALSE)` and still shows #N/A! Error.

I've been looking for any solution but i haven't still found. Can someone please what should i do? Any ideas? Thx in advance for help or any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`=INDEX(Orders!$A$2:$A$6,MATCH(E2,Orders!$B$2:$B$6,0))`

**Results:**

[image]